# Ramda - how to pass dynamic argument to function inside pipe

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to add/use a variable inside the pipe to get the `name` of an object from a different object. Here is what I got so far:

I have an array of IDs `allOutgoingNodes` which I am using in the pipe.
Then I filter results using `tableItemId` property and then I am adding additional property `externalStartingPoint` and after that I would like to add name of `tableItem` from `tableItems` object  to `content -> html` using `concat`.

```
const startingPointId = 395;

const allNodes = {
    "818": {
        "id": "818",
        "content": {
            "html": "<p>1</p>"
        },
        "outgoingNodes": [
            "819"
        ],
        "tableItemId": 395
    },
    "821": {
        "id": "821",
        "content": {
            "html": "<p>4</p>"
        },
        "tableItemId": 396
    }
}

const tableItems = {
    "395": {
        "id": "395",
        "name": "SP1",
        "code": "SP1"
    },
    "396": {
        "id": "396",
        "name": "SP2",
        "code": "SP2"
    }
}

const allOutgoingNodes = R.pipe(
  R.values,
  R.pluck('outgoingNodes'),
  R.flatten
)(tableItemNodes);

const result = R.pipe(
  R.pick(allOutgoingNodes),
  R.reject(R.propEq('tableItemId', startingPointId)),
  R.map(
    R.compose(
      R.assoc('externalStartingPoint', true),
      SomeMagicFunction(node.tableItemId),
      R.over(
        R.lensPath(['content', 'html']),
        R.concat(R.__, '<!-- Table item name should display here -->')
      )
    )
  ),
)(allNodes);
```

Here is a complete working example: [ramda editor](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20startingPointId%20%3D%20395%3B%0A%0Aconst%20tableItemNodes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22818%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22818%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22content%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22html%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E1%3C%2Fp%3E%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22outgoingNodes%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22819%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22tableItemId%22%3A%20395%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22819%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22819%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22content%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22html%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E2%3C%2Fp%3E%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22outgoingNodes%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22820%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22tableItemId%22%3A%20395%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Object%20to%20search%20in%20for%20name%0Aconst%20tableItems%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22395%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22395%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22SP1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22code%22%3A%20%22SP1%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22396%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22396%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22SP2%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22code%22%3A%20%22SP2%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20allNodes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22818%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22818%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22content%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22html%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E1%3C%2Fp%3E%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22outgoingNodes%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22819%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22tableItemId%22%3A%20395%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22819%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22819%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22content%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22html%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E2%3C%2Fp%3E%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22outgoingNodes%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22820%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22tableItemId%22%3A%20395%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22820%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22820%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22content%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22html%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E3%3C%2Fp%3E%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22outgoingNodes%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22821%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22tableItemId%22%3A%20396%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22821%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22821%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22content%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22html%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E4%3C%2Fp%3E%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22tableItemId%22%3A%20396%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%20%20const%20allOutgoingNodes%20%3D%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20R.values%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20R.pluck%28%27outgoingNodes%27%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20R.flatten%0A%20%20%20%20%29%28tableItemNodes%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20R.pick%28allOutgoingNodes%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20R.reject%28R.propEq%28%27tableItemId%27%2C%20startingPointId%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20R.map%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R.compose%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R.assoc%28%27externalStartingPoint%27%2C%20true%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R.over%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R.lensPath%28%5B%27content%27%2C%20%27html%27%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R.concat%28R.__%2C%20%27Table%20item%20name%20goes%20here%27%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%29%28allNodes%29%3B%0A%0Aresult%0A)

Any help and suggestions on how to improve this piece of code will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

In the comments, OriDrori noted a problem with my first version.  I didn't really understand one of the requirements.  This version tries to address that issue.

```js
const {compose, chain, prop, values, lensPath, 
       pipe, pick, reject, propEq, map, assoc, over} = R

const getOutgoing = compose (chain (prop('outgoingNodes')), values)
const htmlLens = lensPath (['content', 'html'])
const addName = (tableItems) => ({tableItemId}) => (html) => 
  html + ` <!-- ${tableItems [tableItemId] ?.name} -->`

const convert = (tableItemNodes, tableItems, startingPointId) => pipe (
  pick (getOutgoing (tableItemNodes)),
  reject (propEq ('tableItemId', startingPointId)),
  map (assoc ('externalStartingPoint', true)),
  map (chain (over (htmlLens), addName (tableItems)))
)

const startingPointId = 395;
const tableItemNodes = {818: {id: "818", content: {html: "<p>1</p>"}, outgoingNodes: ["819"], tableItemId: 395}, 819: {id: "819", content: {html: "<p>2</p>"}, outgoingNodes: ["820"], tableItemId: 395}};
const tableItems = {395: {id: "395", name: "SP1", code: "SP1"}, 396: {id: "396", name: "SP2", code: "SP2"}}
const allNodes = {818: {id: "818", content: {html: "<p>1</p>"}, outgoingNodes: ["819"], tableItemId: 395}, 819: {id: "819", content: {html: "<p>2</p>"}, outgoingNodes: ["820"], tableItemId: 395}, 820: {id: "820", content: {html: "<p>3</p>"}, outgoingNodes: ["821"], tableItemId: 396}, 821: {id: "821", content: {html: "<p>4</p>"}, tableItemId: 396}}

console .log (
  convert (tableItemNodes, tableItems, startingPointId) (allNodes)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

As well as most of the comments on the version below still applying, we should also note that `chain`, when applied to functions acts like this:

```js
chain (f, g) (x) //~> f (g (x)) (x)
```

So `chain (over (htmlLens), addName (tableItems))`

ends up being something like

```js
(node) => over (htmlLens) (addName (tableItems) (node)) (node)
```

which in Ramda is equivalent to

```js
(node) => over (htmlLens, addName (tableItems) (node), node)
```

which we then map over the nodes coming to it.  (You can also see this in [the Ramda REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?const%20getOutgoing%20%3D%20compose%20%28chain%20%28prop%28%27outgoingNodes%27%29%29%2C%20values%29%0Aconst%20htmlLens%20%3D%20lensPath%20%28%5B%27content%27%2C%20%27html%27%5D%29%0Aconst%20addName%20%3D%20%28tableItems%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7BtableItemId%7D%29%20%3D%3E%20%28html%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20html%20%2B%20%60%20%3C%21--%20%24%7BtableItems%20%5BtableItemId%5D%20.name%7D%20--%3E%60%0A%0Aconst%20convert%20%3D%20%28tableItemNodes%2C%20tableItems%2C%20startingPointId%29%20%3D%3E%20pipe%20%28%0A%20%20pick%20%28getOutgoing%20%28tableItemNodes%29%29%2C%0A%20%20reject%20%28propEq%20%28%27tableItemId%27%2C%20startingPointId%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%20%28assoc%20%28%27externalStartingPoint%27%2C%20true%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%20%28chain%20%28over%20%28htmlLens%29%2C%20addName%20%28tableItems%29%29%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconst%20startingPointId%20%3D%20395%3B%0Aconst%20tableItemNodes%20%3D%20%7B818%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%22818%22%2C%20content%3A%20%7Bhtml%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E1%3C%2Fp%3E%22%7D%2C%20outgoingNodes%3A%20%5B%22819%22%5D%2C%20tableItemId%3A%20395%7D%2C%20819%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%22819%22%2C%20content%3A%20%7Bhtml%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E2%3C%2Fp%3E%22%7D%2C%20outgoingNodes%3A%20%5B%22820%22%5D%2C%20tableItemId%3A%20395%7D%7D%3B%0Aconst%20tableItems%20%3D%20%7B395%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%22395%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22SP1%22%2C%20code%3A%20%22SP1%22%7D%2C%20396%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%22396%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22SP2%22%2C%20code%3A%20%22SP2%22%7D%7D%0Aconst%20allNodes%20%3D%20%7B818%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%22818%22%2C%20content%3A%20%7Bhtml%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E1%3C%2Fp%3E%22%7D%2C%20outgoingNodes%3A%20%5B%22819%22%5D%2C%20tableItemId%3A%20395%7D%2C%20819%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%22819%22%2C%20content%3A%20%7Bhtml%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E2%3C%2Fp%3E%22%7D%2C%20outgoingNodes%3A%20%5B%22820%22%5D%2C%20tableItemId%3A%20395%7D%2C%20820%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%22820%22%2C%20content%3A%20%7Bhtml%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E3%3C%2Fp%3E%22%7D%2C%20outgoingNodes%3A%20%5B%22821%22%5D%2C%20tableItemId%3A%20396%7D%2C%20821%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%22821%22%2C%20content%3A%20%7Bhtml%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E4%3C%2Fp%3E%22%7D%2C%20tableItemId%3A%20396%7D%7D%0A%0Aconsole%20.log%20%28%0A%20%20convert%20%28tableItemNodes%2C%20tableItems%2C%20startingPointId%29%20%28allNodes%29%0A%29%0A).)

### Original Answer

It's not trivial to weave extra arguments through a pipeline because pipelines are designed for the simple purpose of passing a single argument down the line, transforming it at every step.  There are of course techniques we could figure out for that, but I would expect them not to be worth the effort.  Because the only thing they gain us would be the ability to write our code point-free.  And point-free should not be a goal on its own.  Use it when it makes your code simpler and more readable; skip it when it doesn't.

Instead, I would break this apart with some helper functions, and then write a main function that took our arguments and passed them as necessary to helper functions inside our main pipeline.  Expand this snippet to see one approach:

```js
const {compose, chain, prop, values, lensPath, flip, concat, 
       pipe, pick, reject, propEq, map, assoc, over} = R

const getOutgoing = compose (chain (prop ('outgoingNodes')), values)
const htmlLens = lensPath (['content', 'html'])
const addName = flip (concat) ('Table item name goes here')

const convert = (tableItemNodes, startingPointId) => pipe (
  pick (getOutgoing (tableItemNodes)),
  reject (propEq ('tableItemId', startingPointId)),
  map (assoc ('externalStartingPoint', true)),
  map (over (htmlLens, addName))
)

const startingPointId = 395;
const tableItemNodes = {818: {id: "818", content: {html: "<p>1</p>"}, outgoingNodes: ["819"], tableItemId: 395}, 819: {id: "819", content: {html: "<p>2</p>"}, outgoingNodes: ["820"], tableItemId: 395}};
const allNodes = {818: {id: "818", content: {html: "<p>1</p>"}, outgoingNodes: ["819"], tableItemId: 395}, 819: {id: "819", content: {html: "<p>2</p>"}, outgoingNodes: ["820"], tableItemId: 395}, 820: {id: "820", content: {html: "<p>3</p>"}, outgoingNodes: ["821"], tableItemId: 396}, 821: {id: "821", content: {html: "<p>4</p>"}, tableItemId: 396}}

console .log (
  convert (tableItemNodes, startingPointId) (allNodes)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

(You can also see this on the [Ramda REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?console%20.clear%20%28%29%0A%0Aconst%20getOutgoing%20%3D%20compose%20%28chain%20%28prop%28%27outgoingNodes%27%29%29%2C%20values%29%0Aconst%20htmlLens%20%3D%20lensPath%20%28%5B%27content%27%2C%20%27html%27%5D%29%0Aconst%20addName%20%3D%20flip%20%28concat%29%20%28%27Table%20item%20name%20goes%20here%27%29%0A%0Aconst%20convert%20%3D%20%28tableItemNodes%2C%20startingPointId%29%20%3D%3E%20pipe%20%28%0A%20%20pick%20%28getOutgoing%20%28tableItemNodes%29%29%2C%0A%20%20reject%20%28propEq%20%28%27tableItemId%27%2C%20startingPointId%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%20%28assoc%20%28%27externalStartingPoint%27%2C%20true%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%20%28over%20%28htmlLens%2C%20addName%29%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconst%20startingPointId%20%3D%20395%3B%0Aconst%20tableItemNodes%20%3D%20%7B818%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%22818%22%2C%20content%3A%20%7Bhtml%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E1%3C%2Fp%3E%22%7D%2C%20outgoingNodes%3A%20%5B%22819%22%5D%2C%20tableItemId%3A%20395%7D%2C%20819%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%22819%22%2C%20content%3A%20%7Bhtml%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E2%3C%2Fp%3E%22%7D%2C%20outgoingNodes%3A%20%5B%22820%22%5D%2C%20tableItemId%3A%20395%7D%7D%3B%0Aconst%20allNodes%20%3D%20%7B818%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%22818%22%2C%20content%3A%20%7Bhtml%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E1%3C%2Fp%3E%22%7D%2C%20outgoingNodes%3A%20%5B%22819%22%5D%2C%20tableItemId%3A%20395%7D%2C%20819%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%22819%22%2C%20content%3A%20%7Bhtml%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E2%3C%2Fp%3E%22%7D%2C%20outgoingNodes%3A%20%5B%22820%22%5D%2C%20tableItemId%3A%20395%7D%2C%20820%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%22820%22%2C%20content%3A%20%7Bhtml%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E3%3C%2Fp%3E%22%7D%2C%20outgoingNodes%3A%20%5B%22821%22%5D%2C%20tableItemId%3A%20396%7D%2C%20821%3A%20%7Bid%3A%20%22821%22%2C%20content%3A%20%7Bhtml%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E4%3C%2Fp%3E%22%7D%2C%20tableItemId%3A%20396%7D%7D%0A%0Aconsole%20.log%20%28%0A%20%20convert%20%28tableItemNodes%2C%20startingPointId%29%20%28allNodes%29%0A%29).)

#### Things to note

- I find `compose (chain (prop ('outgoingNodes')), values)` to be slightly simpler than `pipe (values, pluck('outgoingNodes'), flatten)`, but they work similarly.
- I often separate out the lens definitions even if I'm only going to use them once to make the call site cleaner.
- There is probably no good reason to use Ramda in `addName`.  This would work just as well: `const addName = (s) => s + 'Table item name goes here'` and is cleaner.  I just wanted to show `flip` as an alternative to using the placeholder.
- There is an argument to be made for replacing

  ```js
    map (assoc ('externalStartingPoint', true)),
    map (over (htmlLens, addName))
  ```

  with

  ```
    map (pipe (
      assoc ('externalStartingPoint', true),
      over (htmlLens, addName)
    ))
  ```

  as was done in the original.  The [Functor composition law](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land/#functor) states that they have the same result.  And that requires one fewer iterations through the data.  But it adds some complexity to the code that I wouldn't bother with unless a performance test pointed to this as a problem.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thank you for your solution. Can you check mine?

Answer (score 0):

Before I saw your answer I managed to do something like in the example below:

```
 return R.pipe(
   R.pick(allOutgoingNodes),
   R.reject(R.propEq('tableItemId', startingPointId)),
   R.map((node: Node) => {
     const startingPointName = allTableItems[node.tableItemId].name;
     return R.compose(
       R.assoc('externalStartingPoint', true),
       R.over(
         R.lensPath(['content', 'html']),
         R.concat(
           R.__,
           `<p class='test'>See node in ${startingPointName}</p>`
         )
       )
     )(node);
   }),
   R.merge(newNodesObject)
 )(allNodes);
```

What do you think?

Comment: If it works, that's great.  My growing preference is for my pipelines to contain fairly simple steps, and to extract helper functions to enable this.  Thus the `pick`, `reject`, and `merge` steps all seem fine, but I would choose to extract the function passed to `map` into a named helper function.  But that's your call.